# Удалить часть текста при помощи python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
['Розенфельд А.С.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AПрофессионально-прикладная физическая подготовка студентов аграрного вуза
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S3-3^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
['Цихалевский И.С.', 'Буйносов А.П.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AОрганизация эксплуатации, обслуживания и ремонта газотурбовозов гт1h
#102: RU
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#1107: ^F1^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CВестник Уральского государственного университета путей сообщения^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения"^DЕкатеринбург^S43-55^HN 3 (39)
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2079-0392
*****
['Некрасов К.В.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AИнновационная деятельность организаций отрасли
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S28-28^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
```

Нужно удалить часть текста с "!!!!!!!!!!"(восклицательными знаками). Желаемый результат:

```
['Розенфельд А.С.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AПрофессионально-прикладная физическая подготовка студентов аграрного вуза
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S3-3^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
['Некрасов К.В.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AИнновационная деятельность организаций отрасли
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S28-28^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
****
```

Попыталась сделать при помощи регулярного выражения:

```
import chardet
import re

with open('АРМ.txt', 'rb') as file:
    file_read = file.read()
    result = chardet.detect(file_read)
    f = file_read.decode(result['encoding'])
    print(f)

items = re.sub('*****[^>]+*****', '', f)
print(items)
```

Но выходит ошибка:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно удалить часть текста? Заранее благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` спец-символ регулярок. Чтобы указать в шаблоне именно символ `*`, нужно экранировать его: `\*`.

А чтобы удалить:

```
...

import re
new_text = re.sub('\*{5}.+!+.+?\*{5}', '*****', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(new_text)
```

**PS.**

- `\*{5}` - для поиска `*****`
- `!+` - для поиска набора с восклицательными знаками. По условию попадет от одного восклицательного знака, до сколько угодного.
- `.+?\*{5}` - ленивый поиск до следующего набора `*****`

**PPS.**

Полный пример:

```
text = """\
['Розенфельд А.С.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AПрофессионально-прикладная физическая подготовка студентов аграрного вуза
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S3-3^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
['Цихалевский И.С.', 'Буйносов А.П.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AОрганизация эксплуатации, обслуживания и ремонта газотурбовозов гт1h
#102: RU
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#1107: ^F1^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CВестник Уральского государственного университета путей сообщения^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный университет путей сообщения"^DЕкатеринбург^S43-55^HN 3 (39)
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2079-0392
*****
['Некрасов К.В.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AИнновационная деятельность организаций отрасли
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S28-28^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
"""

import re
new_text = re.sub('\*{5}.+!+.+?\*{5}\n', '', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(new_text)
```

Консоль:

```
['Розенфельд А.С.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AПрофессионально-прикладная физическая подготовка студентов аграрного вуза
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S3-3^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
['Некрасов К.В.']
#920: ASP
#900: ^B08
#200: ^AИнновационная деятельность организаций отрасли
#102: RU
#1107: ^F0^J0^R0^S0^W0^Z0
#463: ^CАграрное образование и наука^J2018^GФедеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего образования "Уральский государственный аграрный университет"^DЕкатеринбург^S28-28^HN 4
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2309-7671
*****
```

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ, но у меня ничего не происходит. И удалить хотелось бы часть текста с восклицательными знаками между *****(звездочками)

Comment: Понял, сейчас допишу :)

Comment: ну, какой же у меня вредный текст. Ничего его не берёт))) Абсолютно никакой реакции.

Comment: @Ireen1985, добавил полный пример, регулярка работает

Comment: теперь и у меня сработало))) Но ещё один нюанс: пропали звездочки перед ['Некрасов К.В.']. Их можно как-то оставить?

Comment: @Ireen1985, и вправду... попробуйте так `new_text = re.sub('\*{5}.+!+.+?\*{5}', '*****', text, flags=re.DOTALL)` (ответ обновил)

Comment: сработало. УРАААА!!! добавила к '*****' \n. Теперь всё идеально))) Спасибо большое

Comment: @Ireen1985, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого:

```
re.sub(r'!!!+\n', '', s)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]